# How to load another table and use it - using linq to sql

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a table in my database called Profile, I have another table called ProfileConfirmed. The purpose of this table is to confirm that the person confirmed his email address. I would like to have it that when I loop through all the profiles, the profiles that have not been confirmed do not show up.

Here is my foreach

```
 @foreach (var c in Model.Profiles)
                            {
}
```

Here is where I am getting the profiles in my models

```
 public List<Cleaner> GetProfiles()
        {
            using (var context = new CleanerDataContext(_connectionString))
            {
                var loadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
                loadOptions.LoadWith<Cleaner>(c => c.ProfileConfirmed);
                context.LoadOptions = loadOptions;
                return context.Cleaners.ToList();

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this part:

return context.Cleaners.ToList();

ToList() method will always get a new copy of the array, though the objects in it aren't copies, they are the same references as in the original array.

```
public List<Cleaner> GetProfiles()
{
    using (var context = new CleanerDataContext(_connectionString))
        {
            var loadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();

            loadOptions.LoadWith<Cleaner>(c => c.ProfileConfirmed);
            context.LoadOptions = loadOptions;

            var confirmedProfilers =
                                  from cust in db.SomeTable
                                  where c.ProfileConfirmed == true
                                  select cust;

           return confirmedProfilers.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you disregard the 2nd table and add an 'IsConfirmed' with a bit data type column on your 1st table. Then

```
var query = (from profiles in context.ProfileTable 
                where IsConfirmed == true select profiles).ToList();
return query;
```

Less code. Less hassle.

Comment: Well it also has a guid in the database to check if the person clicked on the link that was sent to their email.

Comment: You just need to add columns to serve as validations that can be updated once a user verifies his/her account/profile.